# Query field is disabled in edit mode in pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

As the title already says:

I am trying to make a `SELECT` statement in the "view/edit data" mode in pgadmin 4, but the query window is disabled. How can I enable it? (I am the owner of all the database, the schema and table and have all privileges for all of them)

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot edit the query in VIEW DATA mode.
If you want to write custom SELECT/SQL code then use Query tool option.

[image]

Comment: I hate this so much.

Comment: @Intellix Use the latest version, Now using query tool you can edit/update data, View data is no longer the only option for data updation :)

Comment: @MurtuzaZ I have version 4.18 and still can't edit in the view data editor.

Comment: that's the kind of things that let me stay on PgAdmin3

Comment: I hate that the Query Tool starts you off with a blank slate, and that you can't edit the query that it pops out for you in View Mode. Is there a way to get an editable query that includes all column names, like you can with SQL Server Management Studio? It serves as a great jumping off point for doing simple joins and the like.

Comment: Why would anyone think that it is a good idea to prohibit copy and editing SQL in an SQL management tool. This is easy top 5 most infuriating non-feature seen over 25 years of software use. Still so in 5.4

Comment: @user1997614 this is still in 6.10. I think it's time do a fork without this annoying setting.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set a primary key on the table to be able to add items to the table in "View/Edit Data" mode.

Comment: Adding the primary_key into your query?!?! So simple and so frustrating. This should be the real answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to modify the sql query instead of  view/edit data go to Scripts -> Select Script [image]